# How to run (not debug) bash scripts in vscode?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I'm starting to study vscode on linux and trying run bash scripts like hello word.
Install extensions:
ShellCheck
Bash Debug
shell-format

To run script i can use: Menu - Terminal - Run Active file and script run in internal terminal which is not very convenient.

In Geany editor I simply press F5 and the script runs in a new terminal window.

How can I achieve the same behavior for running bash scripts in vscode?

I read the documentation and examples but did not find a solution.

Comment: Would a key binding to perform the "Run Active file" be sufficient?

Comment: Actually I am confused on what it is you want - it seems `F5` by default will run the active file in the terminal https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLZf8.png - is this not the case for you?

Comment: Maybe you want CodeRunner extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner

Comment: what's wrong with `Terminal: Run Active File in Active Terminal`? as long as the active terminal is Bash, or you have an appropriate shebang